# Google Maps is using javascript to render image or image files?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

To use Google Maps API you fetch their api js file with:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=set_to_true_or_false">
</script>
```

Then I use javascript on my page to interact with this API.

I wonder what is going on in the background that I don't see.

Is this file using javascript to render the Google map or is it fetching jpeg files when I zoom in and out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id suggest installing [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), a plugin for Firefox, that will let you see exactly what is going on that you don't see (click the 'Net' tab).

In short though, yes, Google Maps API uses javascript both to render the map and fetch jpeg files when you zoom in and out.